# Best practices for referencing

Tags: cross-referencing

I write a text with a lot of references (`\ref{...}`).
They are predictably showing as a numbers of the same height as the text.

`<phrase>\ref{label}` will looks like '< phrase > 13' with '13' as a hyperlink (I use `hyperref` and compile into PDF).

But am I right in doing this? Should I enclose `\ref` into `\textsuperscript`, so number will not be fused visually with phrase?
What are the best practices for references in the typographical sense?

Comment: If it's not going to be printed, I'd use `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` from package `hyperref` with a coloured link.  Otherwise, a judicious use of `\ref` and `\pageref`, either parenthetically or in a footnote is what I'd recommend.  I also feel that "phrase`\ref{label}`" will not look as good as "phrase (above, `\ref{label}`)" if you want to avoid the footnote option.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, superscripts in the document body are reserved for the usage of references to footnotes. But this is no constraint. You can choose another formatting while beeing consistent to it.

If you don't have any footnotes (with the canonic design) in your manuscript, you can of course put your references into a superscript. Otherwise, be careful.

In most instances I prefer to put references in plain old round brackets (on the level of the text), or use a package like `cleveref` (which provides `\cref`) to automatically paste the origin of the label which you `\ref` to. These constructions can be build in the semantics of your sentences, and look very good without investing much effort.

Comment: One addition to that - don't forget superscripted citation styles.